# How to achieve swipable timeline as seen in twitter's iOS7 app

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uiscrollview, timeline

How does the twitter iOS app achieve the paged swipable timeline? Is it simply 3 UITableView's nested in a paged scrollview or using custom view controller transitions?

[image]
[image]
I tried the nested UITableView approach, but when you scroll down, the content doesn't move under the navigation bar like the twitter app does. Since its the nested UITableView scrolling and not the parent scrollview.

[Original Source link of images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zCUO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently done a very similar behavior using a `UIPageViewController` and `UITableViewController`'s for the content. That's very easy and straight forward to implement. For the dots in the NavigationBar you could just add a custom titleView which holds a UIPageControl

To give an example:

You need a `UIPageViewController` that implements the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. The dataSource asks for the methods:

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

and

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
                      (UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController;
```

where you just need to return the `UITableViewController` instances which present your content.
The swiping etc. is a default behavior of `UIPageViewController`

For a more detailed example have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) which helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it out and it works. But how would you animate the navigation bar title transition though? There doesn't seem to be a reliable way to track the content offset of the UIPageViewController. I could track the offset of the UIScrollView inside the UIPageViewController, but the offset resets when the page changes.